# STM32WB55 Nucleo bluetooth stack firmware binary in bootloader mode

Tags: stm32, bluetooth-low-energy, bootloader

I want to upgrade the firmware for the bluetooth stack on the STM32WB. It requires the device to be in boot loader mode and power from the user USB not ST-LINK usb. However I've not programmed a device in this way before, should it be programmed through the user USB interface, or should i use an ST-Link device and wire up SWDIO...etc to be able to connect to the device?

Instructions provided are below: but they make no reference to using ST-Link.

Following the instructions as is I cannot connect to the device (it doesnt appear in device management) when just connected via USB User.

Should I be using an ST-Link device in addition to the USB user? or any other suggestions?

```
STEP 1: Use STM32CubeProgrammer

    Version 1.4 or higher.

    It gives access to Firmware Upgrade Service (FUS) (AN 5185) through Bootloader.

    It is currently available as Command Line Interface (CLI) mode.

STEP 2: Access to Bootloader USB Interface (system flash)
    Boot mode selected by Boot0 pin set to VDD
        For NUCLEO-WB55.Nucleo :
            Jumper between CN7.5(VDD) and CN7.7(Boot0)
            Power ON via USB_USER and Jumper J2(USB_MCU)
        For NUCLEO-WB55.USBDongle :
            Move switch SW2 to Boot0
            Connect WB55.USBDongle

STEP 3 : Delete current wireless stack :
    STM32_Programmer_CLI.exe -c port=usb1 -fwdelete

STEP 4 : Download new wireless stack :
    STM32_Programmer_CLI.exe -c port=usb1 -fwupgrade [Wireless_Coprocessor_Binary] [Install@] firstinstall=1

Please check Binary Install Address Table for Install@ parameter depending of the binary.

STEP 5 : Revert STEP 2 procedure to put back device in normal mode.
```

Answer (score 1):

The procedure is correct **without** using ST-Link.

Comment: This is not as clearly stated as it could be.   What would be useful to say is that the bootloader speaks USB directly, in contrast to an SWD-based update which would go through an ST-LlNK.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to note to set the BOOT0 jumper. Further, I had some boards that did not respond. Then, I did first flash a simple blink led example to the board (via ST-Link) and then reconnected the board using the User-USB with set BOOT0 jumper (and consequently jumpering the power source on the Nucleo boards between STL and USB as well).

My feeling was that applications using the USB port somehow interfere with the boot loader. This should not be the case with a correctly set jumper, however I did not dig deeper into the topic as the BlinkLed-trick was a quite quick solution.

Further, the firmware update progress consistently quits with something like "Firmware not authentic". However, flashing was successful in these cases as well, so you can ignore the error.